# Clone Folders with Same Cloning technology as actual cloning software. Windows 10 Copy does not work for me

Tags: clone, disk-image, copy

Win 10 Pro - one a Solid state drive I have this 300gig folder called "all MicroSds" When I try to copy this folder it is impossible with cut and paste and it fails both on a move and on a copy.  I can clone this whole drive (with folder "all MicroSds") to another drive no problem.  But if I copy it then it wants 4 days and 21 hours. And it fails with no record of what was copied and what was not copied.
I want to know if technology exists that will allow me to clone folders only with the same technology that is used to clone hard drives.  Is there technology that allows me to clone a folder the same way a hard drive is imaged.  ?  anyone use some kinds of work arounds for this ? Thank you

Comment: run chkdsk on the drive/partition to see if there is anything wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

SO MARCIUM Workstation I did try this and it did work.  It restored my file folder at the rate of 1.5 gig per second. It does appear Macrium has the technology to do what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Macrium file and folder copy is well worth the fee to buy Macrium. If you have a sd card with 900 pictures on it, OR you have a huge group of pictures that are old that were stored on a older HHD hard drive - windows will hang.  when you try to copy them windows hangs in the middle of it all.  I have a group of pictures that took me a VERY LONG TIME to copy because some of the pictures were causing windows to hang. BUT I HAD NO IDEA WHAT PICTURES -   It  was taking days to copy these 2800 pictures.  Macrium folder copy looks at the zeros and the ones and it copies those AND it gets ALL YOUR DATES and ALL your meta data.  What good is 2500 pictures that are all created or modified on the same date. So buy Macrium pro and you will have a real way to copy your pictures. I don't work for Macrium I just know the time it saves me. ITs worth every bit

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/513819) Also please don't post multiple answers with the same solution, instead edit your old answer.